# IE8 Cufon.replace Text Shadow Issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index, cufon, css

Ok, so I'm using Cufon.replace to add a 2px text shadow onto my replaced text, but the problem is, in IE8 for some reason the text shadow is above the text itself, so it looks as if the original text color is the shadow & the replaced shadow is the main text color.

The text is part of my nav bar which is a ul, I've tried adding a z-index:9999; to my nav div and it's parent menu div, but it hasn't changed anything. Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an odd thing. Off the top of my head, if it indeed "is" a z-index issues, don't forget that z-indexed items need to either be position: relative or position: absolute for them to obey. (That has tripped me up a few times.)

Also worth throwing out that IE doesn't support text-shadow (not even in IE9!), and although Cufon may get around that, perhaps that might be an issue too.